# Xcode 14 beta: How to fix errors in Widget Custom Intents?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, widgetkit

I opened the "[Emoji Rangers App Xcode project created by Apple [click to download]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/building_widgets_using_widgetkit_and_swiftui)" for the demo of WidgetKit and wanted to follow up with WWDC22 video.

However, while it worked fine in Xcode 12, when I opened this project in Xcode 13 beta,  I got errors like this:

> Method 'provideHeroOptionsCollection(for:)' with Objective-C selector 'provideHeroOptionsCollectionForDynamicCharacterSelection:withCompletion:' conflicts with method 'provideHeroOptionsCollection(for:with:)' with the same Objective-C selector; this is an error in Swift 6

> Method 'confirm(intent:)' with Objective-C selector 'confirmDynamicCharacterSelection:completion:' conflicts with method 'confirm(intent:completion:)' with the same Objective-C selector; this is an error in Swift 6

> Method 'handle(intent:)' with Objective-C selector 'handleDynamicCharacterSelection:completion:' conflicts with method 'handle(intent:completion:)' with the same Objective-C selector; this is an error in Swift 6

Please help me - how can I fix it?

BTW it's in the `DynamicCharacterSelectionIntent.swift` file, which says:

> // This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Adding widgets to the Lock Screen and watch faces](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/adding_widgets_to_the_lock_screen_and_watch_faces) example project which extends the project you want.

> However, while it worked fine in Xcode 12, when I opened this project in Xcode 13 beta, I got errors like this

You'll need Xcode 14 beta to run it. I don't really understand why would you use Xcode 13 beta these days – it was released a year ago.